# Drawing Latex tree and make arrows in it and change the spaces

Tags: nodes, tikz-trees, forest, trees

I am currently typing a lecture note. Today, I have to  make a tree in Latex.

Style/application: **text boxes and `\tiksstyle`**

Title: **Types of equations**

Types of textboxes:

1. border is black
2. border is white.

### MWE

```latex
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture} [node distance=3cm]



\tikzstyle{box} = [rectangle, minimum width=7cm, minimum height=2cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=white]
\tikzstyle{noboxshort} = [rectangle, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1.98cm, text centered, draw=white, fill=white]

\node (1) [box] {Varia...};
\node (2) [box, below of=1] {Alge...};
\node (2.1) [noboxshort, below of=2, xshift=0cm] {Simple ...};
\node (2.2) [noboxshort, right of=2] {quadra...};
%\node (2.3) [box, right of=2.2] {trigno...};
%\node (2.4) [box, right of=2.3] {diff...};
%\node (3) [box, below of=] {Differ...};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

*The tutorial I followed: [LaTeX Graphics using TikZ: A Tutorial for Beginners (Part 3)—Creating Flowcharts](https://es.overleaf.com/learn/latex/LaTeX_Graphics_using_TikZ%3A_A_Tutorial_for_Beginners_(Part_3)%E2%80%94Creating_Flowcharts)*

*A example I will be using to "grasp" the key concepts in `nodes` and especially the `child` command: [Example: A simple Tree](https://texample.net/tikz/examples/tree/)*

### Modifications

I want to change it:

(free hand drawing roughly explaining the modifications)
[image]

- As the red spaces are the space from the leftmost/rightmost arrow to the rectangle, customizable.
- The pink space is the space between arrows they are equal to each one, customizable.
- (I don't want the arrows bottom-most open ended; they should have nodes below them.)

Thanks,
VScode fanboy.

I am looking forward to different and easy packages and techniques also. Oh and If any can explain how to change the space between a connection/arrow to the textbox, I would be grateful.

PS: I tried installing the `forest` package from the miktex console and the Texmaker, miktex gave me a `Error code:35 ssl error` while Texmaker simply didn't install it and complained about `forest.sty` not existing, looking forward to solutions for this also.

Comment: I would recommend using Tikz, there are plenty of examples here: [Trees examples
](https://texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/trees/)

Comment: These are two unrelated problems. First fix the installation problem. You will frequently need package updates and new packages, so the updating mechanism not working is not an option. Then try the recommended solution. If they don't work for you (other than being not installable), describe what's wrong.

Comment: @gernot Not all packages stopped installing, it will probably probably fixed tomorrow, else, I will profile a GitHub issue. Yes the solution (right now)  is not working: the reason is other than being not install-able ( Answer does not even require the package) - For more info look the comment under the answer as well as my question (updated). Thanks for helping me and trying to get an answer to my questions :).

Comment: @gernot what happened to your answer? I can't see it or copy it, the code and the images are gone. Are you shadow banned or something? I was about to to ask about the technique of `2cm right of {example}` and the other ways you solved my problems such as the two ways for explicitly marking where the arrow should be, etc.

Comment: @gernot _guessing your real intentions and of diff'ing the versions_ You asked me what is the application and I added that to the question. regarding diff'ing only 1 change was done after you answered the question [the adding of the application]. Sorry if the comment bothered you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit unclear as to which type of graph is to be constructed: a flow chart, a tree etc. Depending on the application, there may be packages that allow to specify the graph in a more abstract way.

Here are two ways to control the origin of edges: implicitly by controlling the position of the target node, and explicitly by specifying the origin.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}% for left/below/... = ... of ...
\usetikzlibrary{calc}% for ($...$) coordinate computations
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  activity/.style={draw,minimum width=1cm}
  ]
  \node[activity](A){A};
  \coordinate[below=of A](belowA);
  \node[activity,left=2mm of belowA](C){C};
  \node[activity,left=2mm of C](B){B};
  \node[activity,right=2mm of belowA](D){D};
  \node[activity,right=6mm of D](E){E};
  \path[->] (A) edge (B) edge (C) edge (D) edge (E);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  activity/.style={draw,minimum width=1cm}
  ]
  \node[activity](A){A};
  \coordinate[below=of A](belowA);
  \node[activity,left=5mm of belowA](C){C};
  \node[activity,left=of C](B){B};
  \node[activity,right=5mm of belowA](D){D};
  \node[activity,right=of D](E){E};
  \path[->] (A.south west) edge (B);
  \path[->] (A.south) edge (C);
  \path[->] ($(A.south)+(3mm,0)$) edge (D);
  \path[->] ($(A.south)+(4mm,0)$) edge (E);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Updated the question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/617671/4

Answer (score 3):

Drawing showed image with `forest` is simple:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {
% nodes style
    draw, minimum width=12mm, minimum height=7mm,
% edges
    edge = {-{Straight Barb[angle=60:3pt 4]}, semithick},
% tree grow
    child anchor = north,
    l sep=17mm,
    s sep=5mm,
            }
[root
    [A
        [B] 
        [C]
        [D]
       [E]
    ]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit (1):**
In the case, when lines between the nodes have no arrows heads and nodes on bottom are not present, the above MWE becomes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {
% nodes style
if level = 2{}                                              % <---
            {draw, minimum width=12mm, minimum height=7mm}, % <---
% edges
    edge = {semithick}, % <---
% tree grow
    child anchor = north,
    l sep=17mm,
    s sep=5mm,
            }
[
    [ 
        [ ]
        [ ]
        [ ]
        [ ]
    ]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Since `forest` is based on `tikz`, you can use all its library and make for example nodes more fancy by coloring them, drop shadow, etc. For this see `forest` documentation and search for solutions here on site or employ google for search elsewhere.

An simple dummy example:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                shadows}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {
% nodes style
    draw, minimum width=12mm, minimum height=7mm, align=center,
if level = 2{fill=cyan!10, drop shadow}
            {fill=white, drop shadow},
% edges
    edge = {semithick},
% tree grow
    child anchor = north,
    l sep=17mm,
    s sep=5mm,
            }
[root, font=\bfseries
    [sub root\\ chapters
        [A]
        [B]
        [C]
        [D]
    ]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit (2)**
Since you have some problems with installation of new package, you can meanwhile try the following (onemore) pure `tikz` solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                calc, chains,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 12mm and 6mm,
  start chain = A going right,
   arr/.style = {-Straight Barb, semithick},
   box/.style = {draw, semithick, 
                 text width=12mm, minimum height=7mm, align=center}
                        ]
    \begin{scope}[nodes={box, on chain}]
    \foreach \x in {A,B,C,D}
\node   {\x};    % name=A-\x
    \end{scope}
\node (n2)  [box, above=of $(A-2.north)!0.5!(A-3.north)$]   {};
\node (n1)  [box, above=of n2]                              {};
%
\draw[arr] (n1) -- (n2);
    \foreach \i [count=\j] in {A,B,C,D}
\draw[arr]  (n2) -- (A-\j.north);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks I learned a lot, the accepted answer focused on the problem while you taught me using forest, etc. Not trying to be jerk it's just the way. :) I might also ask some questions on the way.

Comment: Adding for the above comment: [...] as well as coloring them.

Comment: @VScode_fanboy, to solution with `forest` I add a pure `tikz` solution, which can serve you meanwhile  when you will resolve your problem with installing of new packages. Sorry, but I don't understand your second comment. If you have new question how to use `forest`, don't hesitate ask new question.

Comment: yes without `forest` it is valuable, and oh the second comment should be: _first comment_ + _second comment_ = _whole comment_